# Change product name for generated variable products in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

### TL;DR version

How do I change the name that is automatically generated for variable products?

---

### Detailed version

The product variations all get names based on the variable attributes they generate from.

**Example**

Let's say that there's the varible product: Vase.
Vase has the attribute: Condition, with values:

- 'New'
- 'Refurbished'
- 'Used'.

So if I do this (get and output all variation names):

```php
$vase = wc_get_product( $vase_product_id );
$variation_ids = $vase->get_children();
if( !empty( $variation_ids ) ):
    foreach( $variation_ids as $v_id ):
        $variation = wc_get_product( $v_id );
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($variation->get_name());
        echo '</pre>';
    endforeach; // foreach( $variations as $item ):
endif; // if ( !empty( $variations ) )
```

It will output:

```txt
Vase - New
Vase - Refurbished
Vase - Used
```

How do I change this, so it becomes:

```txt
Vase - New condition
Vase - Refurbished condition
Vase - Used condition
```

... So adding the attribute-name after the variation-value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$vase        = wc_get_product( $vase_product_id );
$parent_name = $vase->get_name();

$variation_ids = $vase->get_children();
if ( !empty( $variation_ids ) ):
    foreach ( $variation_ids as $v_id ):
        $variation = wc_get_product( $v_id );
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r( $parent_name . ' - ' . $variation->get_attribute_summary() );
        echo '</pre>';
    endforeach; // foreach( $variations as $item ):
endif;
```

Comment: Do you know how I can make that default behavior for a given attribute? For instance, when I'm using the Product Feed Pro-plugin, I can see that it get's the usual Variation Name (Vase - Used).